# React js onMouseLeave not fire when mouse moves fast

Tags: reactjs, event-delegation

Have a list of following items:

```
function UserItem (props) {

const [showPic, setMode] = useState(false);

return (
<div>
    <div
      onMouseEnter={() => setMode(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setMode(false)}
    >
      {showPic && <div>PIC</div>}  
      {!showPic && <div>{props.login}</div>}
    </div>
</div>    
)
}
```

The problem is that when mouse moved fast onMouseLeave not fire on all items. I understand it has something to do with delegation. But cannot figure out what exactly. Both event should fire on exact element they are attached to.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a bug. But can you try like this?

```
{showPic == true ? <div>PIC</div> : <div>{props.login}</div>}
```

If this still does not work then you should file a bug.